# Does @Singleton in @Binds has any effect during dependency injection in hilt?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, scope, singleton, dagger-hilt

I have an interface

```kotlin
interface TestInterface{
    fun test()
}
```

and its implementation

```kotlin
class TestInterfaceImpl @Inject constructor(): TestInterface{
    override fun test(){}
}
```

To inject the TestInterfaceImpl, I created the following Module

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object Module{ 
   @Singleton
   @Binds
   fun providesImplementation(testImpl: TestInterfaceImpl): TestInterface
}
```

The injected implementation is not singleton even if I annotate providesImplementation() with @Singleton.

However, If I declare TestInterfaceImpl as @Singleton in class declaration, the injected implementation is singleton..

```kotlin
@Singleton
class TestInterfaceImpl @Inject constructor(): TestInterface{
    override fun test(){}
}
```

Does @Singleton have any effect with @Binds in module? if not, should not hilt throw warning stating @Singleton not necessary when you are using @Binds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Singleton on @Binds `TestInterface` and `TestInterfaceImpl` have have different effects.

@Singleton on @Binds `TestInterface` makes `TestInterface` instance singleton, not `TestInterfaceImpl`.

If something requests `TestInterface` instance, Dagger Hilt will provide the singleton on `TestInterface`. But, when requesting `TestInterfaceImpl`, new instance of it will be created and provided.

Comment: Thats what I thought at first. But upon trying, I found that.... If I annotate Binds with Singleton, and inject TestInterface at 2 different place, 2 distinct objects of TestInterfaceImpl are injected... However if I annotate TestInterfaceImpl with Singleton and inject TestInterface, I get same object of TestInterfaceImpl every time.

Comment: @DikenMhrz I just tested `Singleton` on `Binds` and I worked as expected.
My test code : https://pastebin.com/1A0nh5vS
Dependency1 and Dependency2 have `TestInterface` as a dependency, I checked their dependency's instances are same with === operator. The result is true as expected.
Dependency3 and Depedency4 have `TestInterfaceImpl` and their instances are different.

Comment: @DikenMhrz Can you show me your code?

Comment: I am not sure what I did the last time. But its working as expected. Thanks for your time..

Comment: Also for future readers, if we annotate TestInterfaceImpl as Singleton, it does not matter if we inject TestInterface or TestInterfaceImpl, we get same instance of TestInterfaceImpl (provided TestInterface is bound with TestInterfaceImpl)..